# Is there a reward for smashing green pumpkins?

Tags: ok-golf

OK Golf’s 1.70 update added hidden green pumpkins to various courses throughout the game.

> PUMPKIN HUNT - Can you smash all the green pumpkins hidden throughout the game? They won’t hang around for long...

The pause menu implies that there are a total of 50 pumpkins to smash.

Is there any reward for smashing these green pumpkins?

[image: counter for green pumpkins]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[After several days of pumpkin hunting](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/322443/181240), I can confirm that smashing 50 pumpkins will unlock "*Hallows Creek - Hole 12 (The Hole Truth)*"**

[image]

For a complete list of all 50 pumpkin locations, see *[Where are the green pumpkins located?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/322443/181240)*.

---

[According to a forum post by the game's developer on TouchArcade](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showpost.php?p=4059105&postcount=314), smashing all 50 pumpkins will unlock a secret hole for the game's 10th course, Hallows Creek.

> We head off to Colorado next week where things will get a little
>   spooky.
>
> But in a break with tradition, we've crept in a third secret hole.
>   Smash all the green pumpkins hidden throughout the **entire game** and
>   you'll unlock it. The ghastly pumpkins will only remain until the next
>   course is added, but if you unlock the hole before then you'll be able
>   to visit the new haunt until your phone gives up the ghost.