# Where are the green pumpkins located?

Tags: ok-golf

In an [earlier question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/322233/181240) I mentioned that OK Golf's 1.70 update added green pumpkins hidden throughout the game. [According to the developer](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showpost.php?p=4059105&postcount=314), smashing all 50 pumpkins will unlock *The Hole Truth*, the third secret hole for Hallows Creek.

Where are the green pumpkins hidden in OK Golf? Which holes are they on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After several days of searching, here are the locations of all <s>50</s> *51* green pumpkins in OK Golf. I've listed each location with a screenshot below.

**Notes**:

- There is an extra 51<sup>th</sup> green pumpkin, making it possible to collect 51/50 pumpkins.
- The 1.82 update added [50 hidden gifts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/323059/181240) as the default collectable. You can switch between hunting gifts or pumpkins in the settings menu.

---

## Green Pumpkin locations in OK Golf

#### Long Lake County • Georgia, USA (7)

- **Hole 2:** [In the rough by the trees. Look forward from the starting tee.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoKAO.jpg)
- **Hole 3:** [On the small island between the tee and the hole.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12Rf4.jpg)
- **Hole 4:** [In the rough in-between the green and the trees.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr2Kg.jpg)
- **Hole 5:** [Turn the camera around. It's out-of-bounds behind the tee.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gExmY.jpg)
- **Hole 7:** [On top of a rock located left of the starting tee.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzkTZ.jpg)
- **Hole 9**: [Located on a rock by the lighthouse near the green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44Egp.jpg)
- **Hole 11 (*Are We There Yet?*):** [To the left of the green on the fairway.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GLsp.jpg)

#### Desert Canyon • Arizona, USA (7)

- **Hole 1:** [Behind some cacti near the hill to the right of the tee.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esq2e.jpg)
- **Hole 2**: [In-between two cacti next to the green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYjIm.jpg)
- **Hole 3:** [To the right of the tee on a small patch of fairway. In-between the hill and water.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ydh3.jpg)
- **Hole 5:** [On top of a large rock behind the green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jcl0E.jpg) (*This one is tricky. I recommend chipping from the green-edge.*)
- **Hole 6:** [On the gray pathway to the right of the tee.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJQsg.jpg)
- **Hole 9:** [Under the windmill next to the green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZwxn.jpg)
- **Hole 10 (*The Road Less Traveled*):** [On a small square patch of fairway to the left.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExCjx.jpg)

#### Tsukimi Garden • Kyoto, Japan (6)

- **Hole 1:** [Hidden in the trees to the left in between the tee and the green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKFZb.jpg)
- **Hole 2:**  [Near the starting tee on the fairway next to the lake on the left.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZtI1.jpg)
- **Hole 3:** [Behind the four trees to the left of the tee.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7LS2.jpg)
- **Hole 7:** [On the pavement behind the trees next to the lantern.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URIKM.jpg)
- **Hole 9:** [By the small pond next to the red bridge.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ruE4.jpg)
- **Hole 10 (*Long Way Round*):** [Hidden in the trees next to the small pond near the tee.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rHe8.jpg)

#### Pahoehoe Ridge • Hawaii, USA (6)

- **Hole 1:** [To the right between two palm trees. Visible from the tee.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJbug.jpg)
- **Hole 3:** [Stranded on a rock surrounded by water next to the green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNEox.jpg)
- **Hole 6:** [On a rock surrounded by water in the middle of the hole. Placed above the secret hole.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbR9P.jpg)
- **Hole 7:** [Submerged in water to the left of the tee.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzAvE.jpg)
- **Hole 9:** [Out of bounds behind the green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6Yh9.jpg)
- **Hole 10 (*Abandoned Course*):** [In a patch of rough on the right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzJDH.jpg)

#### Buchan Bay • Aberdeen, Scotland (4)

- **Hole 2:** [Hovering above a bunker next to the green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcaqG.jpg)
- **Hole 4:** [Near some ruins in the rough.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKtJN.jpg)
- **Hole 8:** [By some gravestones near a time tower.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Z1tL.jpg)
- **Hole 11 (*Fort Fore*):** [Atop the left pillar in the lake.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4n6y.jpg)

#### Miami Palms • Florida, USA (4)

- **Hole 2:** [By some palm trees to the right of the tee.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZ0nl.jpg)
- **Hole 4:** [On the fairway next to a bunker.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnpW9.jpg)
- **Hole 7:** [In a small pool surrounded by trees.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSENl.jpg)
- **Hole 9:** [On a small fairway island surrounded by trees.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUPhQ.jpg)

#### Oakford Woods • Somerset, England (5)

- **Hole 1:** [On a patch of fairway in the trees to the left.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRS7P.jpg)
- **Hole 2:** [Next to the house in the trees.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGIxf.jpg)
- **Hole 4:** [Next to two houses in the trees.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDFMM.jpg)
- **Hole 6:** [In the corner of the map in the rough surrounded by trees.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwWML.jpg)
- **Hole 10 (*A Model Town*):** [A giant pumpkin towers out-of-bounds to the right of the green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Co1fK.jpg) (*This one's pretty hard to miss*)

#### Paris Rooftops • Paris, France (2)

- **Hole 2:** [Left of the tee by the chimney.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rhiC.jpg)
- **Hole 5:** [Hidden on a windowsill on the side of the starting building.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtJtf.jpg)

#### Kaski Pass • Grandaki, Nepal (3)

- **Hole 1:** [In the rough next to the multi-colored flag.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWNF4.jpg)
- **Hole 2:** [In the corner behind the green next to some trees.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6da2y.jpg)
- **Hole 5:** [On a small raised ledge in the rough.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvhw5.jpg)

#### Hallows Creek • Colorado, USA (7)

- **Hole 1:** [In a wheelbarrow in the pumpkin patch to the right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHQxG.jpg)
- **Hole 2:** [Next to some hay in the pumpkin patch to the right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrOFQ.jpg)
- **Hole 4:** [Next to a scarecrow in the pumpkin patch to the right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fBwR.jpg)
- **Hole 6:** [On a small path of fairway left of the green behind two trees.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj2zB.jpg)
- **Hole 7:** [Near the corner in the pumpkin patch to the right where the secret hole is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aefjN.jpg)
- **Hole 9:** [Behind the glowing jack-o-lantern in the trees to the left.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLxOX.jpg)
- **Hole 10 (*Maze of Scarecrows*):** [Near the back-left corner, behind some trees.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zt1Ix.jpg)